# Call Javascript object with string variable

Tags: javascript

If I have a javascript object like this...

```
window.object = 
{
    "Element1" :
    {
        "startDate" : "-1m",
        "endDate" : "0d"
    }
};
```

I can use the below code to alert out -1m...

```
alert(object.Element1.startDate);
```

However, what if Element1 was given to me through a parameter as a string. How could I get the same result if I have to use a variable? Like this but not correct...

```
var elementId = this.id;
alert(object.elementId.startDate);
```

Comment: whats the format of the string?

Comment: and [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
object[elementId].startDate
```

Or if `id` is a number , this will work:

```
object["Element"+elementId].startDate
```

Comment: your first answer captures all cases

Comment: Console is catching an error, object[elementId] is undefined

Comment: @gmustudent so something wrong with your `this.id` and as result after this part: `var elementId = this.id;` your `elementId` is undefined

Comment: Sorry. unrelated issue to why I had a problem. Will accept after time limit

Comment: @Yaw i'm just right now reading about `Objects` in Douglas Crockford' book , that is my little secret ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global object `this`:

```
var Element1 = 'boo';

var stringname = 'Element1';
alert(this[stringname]);
```

A second, hacky, method, is that javascript can print javascript and that printed javascript will also be interpreted.

Comment: If you use `window` instead of `this`, you can access global variables everywhere not only in global scope. What do you mean by *"javascript can print javascript and that printed javascript will also be interpreted"*? Could you provide an example?

Comment: If you do `document.write('<scrip' + 't>alert("boo");</scrip' + 't>');`, it will give you an alert. Breaking up the script tag may or may not be necessary depending on context, I believe.